# Unity Photon PUN connection error with Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, photon

I'm working with Unity and the Photon Engine (PUN). I used the DemoSynchronization-Scene as an example and tested different devices. The connection with all other devices is totally fine but I get an error with the Hololens.

```
Connect() to 'ns.exitgames.com' failed: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
A network capability is required to access this network resource
   at Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket.ConnectAsync(EndpointPair endpointPair, SocketProtectionLevel protectionLevel)
   at ExitGames.Client.Photon.SocketTcpNetFxCore.<ConnectSync>d__13.MoveNext()
```

Do I need to grant some specific network access on the Hololens?

Comment: You would need to be registered and you would need to get an application ID, That is the reason you are getting Access is denied

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not give your app network capabilities/permissions.

To do so, go to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Player`.

In the `Inspector` pane, click on the `Universal Windows Platform settings` icon,

[image: Windows Universal Platform Settings]

scroll down to `Publishing Settings` and inside the `Capabilities` box check both `InternetClient` and `InternetClientServer`.

[image: UWP capabilities on Unity3D]